# Constrain upstream dependencies in pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, python-packaging

I need to specify a version for a package that one of my dependencies depends on, but my package does not directly depend on. Say my CI is trying to build package_a, it depends on package_b and does not depend on package_c. But package_b depends on package_c and it needs to be a particular version. In other words, "don't install this, but if you end up installing this, please install this version."

This appears to be doable in conda with [run_constrainted](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/pull/2001) but I cannot determine if it is possible to do in pip in the requirements.

A less appealing workaround would just be to add this other package (package_c) as another requirement.